# Radeon Vega20 Macbook Pro with eGPU Radeon RX Vega 56 for Create ML

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm trying to figure out if the eGPU will actually help with CreateML on a maxed out Macbook with the Vega20 GPU.

For NVIDIA, I understand that both graphics card have to be the same - so I am not sure if the Vega 20 and Vega 56 would run together?

Would it help with the Create ML app?